# Jenkins pipeline with custom docker image as agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need some help getting Jenkins to work with a docker image as it's execution environment. Admittedly I am a total noob when it comes to working with Jenkins and I've tried to search for an answer but the majority of the results talk about building a docker image within a pipeline, but that's not what I need to do.

I have this as my Dockerfile in a separate project. It simply sets up an image that contains Python, Node, NPM and the Serverless Framework package. Nothing fancy.

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

ENV NODE_MAJOR 18

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg && \
    mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg && \
    echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install nodejs -y

RUN useradd -m jenkins

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER jenkins
ENV NPM_PACKAGES="/home/jenkins/.npm-packages"
ENV PATH="$PATH:$NPM_PACKAGES/bin"
RUN mkdir -p $NPM_PACKAGES && \
    npm config set prefix $NPM_PACKAGES

RUN npm install -g serverless

WORKDIR /workspace
```

This is then referenced in my Jenkinsfile and I can see it pulling down the image in the output, however when I run some sanity checks to see what's installed, the commands are not executed within the container like I imagine they should be.

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    environment {
        DOCKER_REGISTRY = '<account>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
        ECR_IMAGE = '<account>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<team>-ci:latest'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Get docker image from AWS ECR') {
            agent any
            steps {
                withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', credentialsId: 'aws-credentials-ecr', secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]) {
                    script {
                        def token = sh(script: 'aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1', returnStdout: true).trim()
                        sh "docker login -u AWS --password ${token} ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}"
                        sh "docker pull $ECR_IMAGE"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Setup & Run Inside Container') {
            agent { docker { image "$ECR_IMAGE" } }
            stages {
                stage('Jenkins debugging') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'pwd'
                        sh 'whoami'
                        sh 'which serverless'
                        sh 'npm list -g --depth=0'

                    }
                }
                stage('Version Check') {
                    steps {
                        sh '''
                        npm --version
                        node --version
                        serverless --version
                        python --version'''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
                
}
```

I am fairly certain the issue is with mounting and/or the user being used, but like I said above I can't find a solution so I'm turning to the experts on SOF.

When I run the image locally with docker and issue the npm list command the output is

```
jenkins@e80e54dcc161:~$ npm list -g --depth=0
/home/jenkins/.npm-packages/lib
├── jwt-decode@3.1.2
└── serverless@3.35.2
```

However running it from Jenkins gives me

```
+ npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/lib
├── corepack@0.19.0
└── npm@9.8.1
```

Thanks for any help or guidance!

Comment: Can you check from the logs, if the `docker pull` and the subsequent stages are running on the same node?

Comment: Same worker for the steps that do complete and the one that fails

Comment: Interesting. Could you paste the output log from the Jenkins build? What is the type of the agent used in the build?